# How to get current user data from firebase realtime database in React Native

Tags: firebase, react-redux, firebase-authentication, react-native

I'm trying to get **current signed user's** **image and name** **from the firebase realtime database** in which his data was stored when he signup. I want to put these two items in the drawer header. [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NZiTt.png)You can see the attached screenshots.

Here is the current user
[image]

here is the data of the current user. I want to get that data on the basis of current user signed in

[image]

Answer (score 4):

you can get the `currentUser.uid` if you are loggedin with firebase.

try my code,

```
firebase
      .database()
      .ref('Users/' + firebase.auth().currentUser.uid)
      .once('value')
      .then(snapshot => {
        console.log(snapshot.val()) <--will print the user data
      });
```

hope this works for you.

Answer (score 1):

Try making an async function so you can retrieve data from any user with just the UID like this:

```
export async function getUserByUID(UID) {
  return await firebase.database().ref(`Users/${UID}`).once('value');
}
```

Later you can simply pass the UID and get any users' data:

```
const getMyData = async () => {
  let UID = firebase.auth().currentUser.uid;
  let userData = await getUserDataByUID(UID);
  // this will be null if there's no user data
  // all users' data will be in userData for example:
  console.log(userData.image) // will log the image url you saved.
}
```

BTW don't forget your firebase database rules! The last thing you want is other seeing those passwords!!

Answer (score 0):

check the following code

```
 firebase.database().ref(`Users/${firebase.auth().currentUser.uid}`).once('value', function (snapshot) {
        console.log(snapshot.val())
    });
```